# Manter registros de tabelas sincronizados entre dois bancos de dados diferentes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

Estamos realizando uma migração de sistema, onde será feita algumas reestruturações no banco atual em um banco novo. Basicamente terei dois bancos `BancoVelho` e `BancoNovo`, tendo que manter os dois atualizados conforme o mapeamento das tabelas que foram ou não reestruturadas.

Então, teria que manter atualizada as seguintes tabelas

```
CREATE TABLE [BANCO_VELHO].[dbo].[FRANQUIA_TIPO](
    [ID_FRANQUIA_TIPO] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CODIGO] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [DESCRICAO] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ID_FRANQUIA_TIPO_MASTER] [int] NULL,   
    [DATA_HORA_CADASTRO_ALTERACAO] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ATIVO] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ID_USUARIO_CADASTRO_ALTERACAO] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FRANQUIA_TIPO] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_FRANQUIA_TIPO] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

--

```
CREATE TABLE [BancoNovo].[dbo].[FranquiaTipo](
    [FranquiaTipoId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Descricao] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [FranquiaTipoMasterId] [int] NULL,
    [UsuarioCad] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [DataHoraCad] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Ativo] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.FranquiaTipo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [FranquiaTipoId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Então estou pensando em criar uma `Trigger` no banco que faça esse trabalho.

O sistema novo que será desenvolvido será em `ASP.NET MVC` usando `EntityFramework`.

Baseando na ideia de criar `Trigger`, cheguei a seguinte `Trigger`

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Tondolo, Pablo
-- Create date: 15:18 22/04/2016
-- Description: Trigger responsável por manter atualizado o banco de dados do sistema em delphi
--              com o sistema em C#
-- =============================================

use BancoNovo

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

if exists (select null from sys.objects where name = 'FranquiaTipoConexaoTrigger')
    drop trigger FranquiaTipoConexaoTrigger

go

CREATE TRIGGER FranquiaTipoConexaoTrigger
   ON  FranquiaTipo
   FOR INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --
    if exists (select null from deleted) 
    begin
        if exists (select null from inserted)
        begin

            DECLARE tmp CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
            SELECT [FranquiaTipoId]
                  ,[Descricao]
                  ,[FranquiaTipoMasterId]
                  ,[UsuarioCad]
                  ,[DataHoraCad]
                  ,[Ativo]
            FROM inserted

            declare @FranquiaTipoId integer
            declare @Descricao varchar(100)
            declare @FranquiaTipoMasterId integer
            declare @UsuarioCad varchar(100)
            declare @DataHoraCad datetime
            declare @Ativo bit

            OPEN tmp
            FETCH NEXT FROM tmp
            INTO  @FranquiaTipoId, @Descricao, @FranquiaTipoMasterId, @UsuarioCad, @DataHoraCad, @Ativo

            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN   
                print 'update ' + @Descricao

                UPDATE [BANCO_VELHO].[dbo].[FRANQUIA_TIPO]
                   SET 
                       --[CODIGO] = [CODIGO]
                      [DESCRICAO] = @Descricao
                      ,[ID_FRANQUIA_TIPO_MASTER] = @FranquiaTipoMasterId
                      --,[PERCENTUAL_CONSULTOR_FIXO] = <PERCENTUAL_CONSULTOR_FIXO, bit,>
                      --,[PERCENTUAL_SENIOR_FIXO] = <PERCENTUAL_SENIOR_FIXO, bit,>
                      --,[PERCENTUAL_ROYALTIES_SENIOR] = <PERCENTUAL_ROYALTIES_SENIOR, numeric(18,2),>
                      --,[PERCENTUAL_ROYALTIES_CONSULTOR] = <PERCENTUAL_ROYALTIES_CONSULTOR, numeric(18,2),>
                      --,[PERCENTUAL_PUBLICIDADE_SENIOR] = <PERCENTUAL_PUBLICIDADE_SENIOR, numeric(18,2),>
                      --,[PERCENTUAL_PUBLICIDADE_CONSULTOR] = <PERCENTUAL_PUBLICIDADE_CONSULTOR, numeric(18,2),>
                      --,[PERCENTUAL_TAXA_RISCO_SENIOR] = <PERCENTUAL_TAXA_RISCO_SENIOR, numeric(18,2),>
                      --,[PERCENTUAL_TAXA_RISCO_CONSULTOR] = <PERCENTUAL_TAXA_RISCO_CONSULTOR, numeric(18,2),>
                      ,[DATA_HORA_CADASTRO_ALTERACAO] = @DataHoraCad
                      ,[ATIVO] = @Ativo
                      ,[ID_USUARIO_CADASTRO_ALTERACAO] = (SELECT ID_USUARIO FROM BANCO_VELHO.DBO.USUARIO WHERE USUARIO.LOGIN = @UsuarioCad)
                 WHERE ID_FRANQUIA_TIPO = @FranquiaTipoId


                FETCH NEXT FROM tmp
                INTO  @FranquiaTipoId, @Descricao, @FranquiaTipoMasterId, @UsuarioCad, @DataHoraCad, @Ativo                 
            END

            CLOSE tmp
            DEALLOCATE tmp

        end
        else
        begin
            print 'delete'
            DELETE FROM [BANCO_VELHO].[dbo].[FRANQUIA_TIPO]
            WHERE EXISTS (
                SELECT NULL
                FROM DELETED A
                WHERE [BANCO_VELHO].[dbo].[FRANQUIA_TIPO].[ID_FRANQUIA_TIPO] = A.FranquiaTipoId
            )
        end
    end
    else
    begin
        print 'insert'
        set identity_insert [BANCO_VELHO].[dbo].[FRANQUIA_TIPO] on
        INSERT INTO [BANCO_VELHO].[dbo].[FRANQUIA_TIPO]
                   ([ID_FRANQUIA_TIPO]
                   ,[CODIGO]
                   ,[DESCRICAO]
                   ,[ID_FRANQUIA_TIPO_MASTER]
                   ,[PERCENTUAL_CONSULTOR_FIXO]
                   ,[PERCENTUAL_SENIOR_FIXO]
                   ,[PERCENTUAL_ROYALTIES_SENIOR]
                   ,[PERCENTUAL_ROYALTIES_CONSULTOR]
                   ,[PERCENTUAL_PUBLICIDADE_SENIOR]
                   ,[PERCENTUAL_PUBLICIDADE_CONSULTOR]
                   ,[PERCENTUAL_TAXA_RISCO_SENIOR]
                   ,[PERCENTUAL_TAXA_RISCO_CONSULTOR]
                   ,[DATA_HORA_CADASTRO_ALTERACAO]
                   ,[ATIVO]
                   ,[ID_USUARIO_CADASTRO_ALTERACAO])
            SELECT FranquiaTipoId --[ID_FRANQUIA_TIPO]
                   ,NULL --[CODIGO]
                   ,Descricao --[DESCRICAO]
                   ,FranquiaTipoMasterId --[ID_FRANQUIA_TIPO_MASTER]
                   ,0 --[PERCENTUAL_CONSULTOR_FIXO]
                   ,0 --[PERCENTUAL_SENIOR_FIXO]
                   ,0 --[PERCENTUAL_ROYALTIES_SENIOR]
                   ,0 --[PERCENTUAL_ROYALTIES_CONSULTOR]
                   ,0 --[PERCENTUAL_PUBLICIDADE_SENIOR]
                   ,0 --[PERCENTUAL_PUBLICIDADE_CONSULTOR]
                   ,0 --[PERCENTUAL_TAXA_RISCO_SENIOR]
                   ,0 --[PERCENTUAL_TAXA_RISCO_CONSULTOR]
                   ,DataHoraCad --[DATA_HORA_CADASTRO_ALTERACAO]
                   ,[ATIVO]
                   ,(SELECT ID_USUARIO FROM BANCO_VELHO.DBO.USUARIO WHERE USUARIO.LOGIN = UsuarioCad)--[ID_USUARIO_CADASTRO_ALTERACAO]
            FROM inserted
            set identity_insert [BANCO_VELHO].[dbo].[FRANQUIA_TIPO] OFF
    end


END
GO
```

Para esse caso só vou atualizar do sistema novo para o velho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Então estou pensando em criar uma *Trigger* no banco que faça esse trabalho.

É a única alternativa viável, sobretudo considerando que a tecnologia no sistema antigo não é sofisticada como no sistema novo.

Note que não será uma *Trigger* por operação, mas duas. Supondo que você esteja inserindo na tabela nova, mas queira manter um espelhamento na antiga, a tabela nova também precisará de *Triggers*.

Para o sistema novo, procure deixar a aplicação subir o banco através de *Migrations*, e coloque as *Triggers* nessas *Migrations*, assim:

```
public partial class Exemplo : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        /* Código gerado pelo Scaffolding */
        Sql("CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER [nomedatrigger] BEFORE UPDATE ON FranquiaTipo ...");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        /* Código gerado pelo Scaffolding */
        Sql("DROP TRIGGER [nomedatrigger]");
    }
}
```

---

Seu exemplo de *Trigger* está interessante, mas eu faria algo mais simples:

```
CREATE TRIGGER FranquiaTipo_BancoVelho_DEL
ON [BancoNovo].[dbo].[FranquiaTipo]
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM [BANCO_VELHO].[dbo].[FRANQUIA_TIPO]
    WHERE ID_FRANQUIA_TIPO = DELETED.FranquiaTipoId 
END
```

---

```
CREATE TRIGGER FranquiaTipo_BancoVelho_UPD
ON [BancoNovo].[dbo].[FranquiaTipo]
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE [BANCO_VELHO].[dbo].[FRANQUIA_TIPO]
    SET CODIGO = I./* Coloque aqui a coluna de código */
    FROM INSERTED I
    WHERE [BANCO_VELHO].[dbo].[FRANQUIA_TIPO].ID_FRANQUIA_TIPO = I.FranquiaTipoId
END
```

Uma *Trigger* por operação pode parecer prolixo, mas funciona melhor que uma *Trigger* para todos os casos.

As demais *Triggers* são análogas a estas.

Comment: Entendi, mas minha duvida maior é como ficaria essa `Trigger`?

Comment: Acho que ta me faltando um pouco de conceito sobre o que utilizar, se `FOR`, `AFTER` .... `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, mas vou dar uma estudada, qualquer dúvida posto aqui no SO

Comment: @PabloVargas Por favor, atualize sua pergunta com os nomes de cada *database* para que eu possa dar os exemplos.

Comment: Mas ta na pergunta já o nome dos bancos, `BANCO_VELHO` e `BancoNovo`

Comment: Cigano, lembrando é sql server

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com exemplos.

Comment: Cigano, se bem me lembro, a `Trigger` `for update`, tem que usar `cursor`, pois como ficaria um `UPDATE` sem clausula `where`? se não me engano, se não tiver `cursor`, só vai executar o update pro primeiro registro da tabela.

Comment: Sim, se vir em lote, acho que precisa iterar. Meu exemplo foi bem simples, apenas para você ver que tipo de divisão pode fazer para facilitar seu trabalho.

Comment: Blz, acho que vou dividir o exemplo que fiz

Answer (score 0):

Melhor usar SQL Server Replication, assumindo os dois bancos de dados estão em SQL Server. SQL Server tem três tipos de replication: Transactional, Merge, e Snapshot. Neste caso, Transactional poderia ser conveniente.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152531(SQL.110).aspx

Usar triggers seria muito fragil e teria dificuldades: como processar erros,  locking, etc.

Em qualquer caso, é melhor não usar Cursors porque são muito ineficiente. SQL Server funciona com sets.

Comment: vou estudar sobre o assunto. Sobre o não usar Cursors, como ficaria o meu update sem ele?

Comment: Veja o livro Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2008 T-SQL Programming de Itzik Ben-Gan, Chapter 8: Cursors. Ele explica o porquê não usar cursors.

Comment: Training Kit 70-462 Administering Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Databases - Chapter 7 Mirroring and Replication - Lesson 2: Database Replication